# Routing Strategy Laravel vs. Symfony

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I'm developing a Router for PHP and I see Laravel and Symfony has 2 approaches. Laravel Routes are in a file and you say this controller and that method but in Symfony routing is in the controllers.
the difference is in Laravel we only load one controller but in Symfony, we should load all controllers then find a correct controller and method for our path.
My Questions is :
1- Are there any performance difference between these two(Loading 1 controller vs Loading multiple controllers)?
2- Except performance which one is better Strategy?

Comment: In Symfony, you can define routes in annotations (controller) or in a specific file, or both.

Comment: By the way, symfony won't load all controllers, but roam them until the route matches

Comment: @Cid oh, thanks I didn't know about that

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, Symfony does not "roam" through all controllers until a match is found.  Instead, Symfony has what it calls a "compile" phase.  This phase checks all the controllers, pulls out any routes and then caches the results.  When it comes time to match a route the cached information is used.  So there is no difference in performance between the two approaches.